# The Macedonian (mk) language is not taken the translations given in template setup in TYPO3

Tags: typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am using Typo3 version 9.5.13 with 16 languages, there is a language 'Macedonian(mk)' and I have added a translation for this language with a key in Typo3 template setup, but it's not taking this translation and shows the default translation. This language is not in the Typo3 Supported languages list.

Thank you

Comment: plugin.tx_my_ext._LOCAL_LANG.mk.key = value

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Internationalization/Languages.html

Comment: OK. Please also post how you are trying to access that string. (In backend TCA, Fluid or TypoScript, ...)

Comment: I am sorry. I must have been wrong. mk support does not seem to be complete.

Comment: It is included in TYPO3 since 9.5.14 now: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for TYPO3 to support "mk" locale (and thus, XLF-based label files with "mk.locallang.xlf") one needs to add this line to `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['localization']['locales']['user']['mk'] = 'Macedonian';`

This is the beginning to make it even possible to allow `mk` for TYPO3 Backend and Frontend - related to label files (XLF).

The other parts (creating a `sys_language` record, adding an icon, adding "mk" to the site language etc) are still valid and need to be done as well, in order to determine "mk" in a multi-language setup for TYPO3 Frontend.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add the language to typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/TCA/sys_language.php
2. Insert the translation of the language to typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Private/Language/db.xlf
3. Add the locale to typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Localization/Locales.php
4. Add the flag icon to the IconRegistry: typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/IconRegistry.php
5. Add the icon identifier to typo3/sysext/backend/Configuration/SiteConfiguration/site_language.php

You can see an example for Maori here:
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commit/a8c16c45f8a1fce1d858815cef6c1ad83cff5d76

Comment: The mk language is already present. Also it is not good practice to edit core files directly.

Comment: Hey Jonas, TYPO3 Core does not support "mk" language out of the box. See Locales.php. Maybe we should add this as a feature in TYPO3 v10?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look thoroughly. The language icon and sys_language is present, but Locale is missing.